# What is the command to upgrade Heroku Postgresql to a Basic plan

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I need to upgrade my Heroku Postgresql database to the Basic plan.  I've found the command in Heroku's docs, but I'm not sure if I need to change it to affect my account.  My app's name on Heroku is  `tranquil-mountain-51138`

`heroku addons:upgrade HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_LAVENDER_URL heroku-postgresql:premium-0 -a sushi`

Do I need to change this terminal command to include my app's name and the Basic db plan?  If so, could you give me the edited version. My guess would be that I change `premium-0` to `basic`.  I've no idea what the rest of the command refers to: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_LAVENDER_URL` and `sushi`

It is a very small personal app. I'm the only one using it, so I've no worries about down time when the maintenance starts.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Finally received a response from Herouku HelpDesk that explains the parts of their example command for upgrading a db.

Their example: `heroku addons:upgrade HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_LAVENDER_URL heroku-postgresql:premium-0 -a sushi`

`$heroku addons:upgrade DATABASE_URL <database-type> -a <app-name>`

For my app, upgrading to their Basic plan, the command is:

`$heroku addons:upgrade DATABASE_URL heroku-postgresql:basic -a tranquil-mountain-51138`

Hope this helps others.